# issue with appengine dynamic instance

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a class which does something (initialization ) when my app first starts.This initialization code is present in static block .So normally should be executed only once when the class loads for first time.

Now when the problem is as my instance is dynamic when there are no requests coming to my server my app gets unloaded .So next time when a request comes app is loaded dynamically and initialization code runs again.This is what i dont want.

I know this problem can be solved by using resident instance.But i guess resident instance is not available in free quota.Correct me if i am wrong.

Is there any way by which i can get away with this problem?

Storing the result of calculation in db is one option buts its not feasible as i want that data quickly?
How about memchace?Will it work?Will the data in memchace preserverd across dynamic loading of my app?
Note:I am not explicitly unloading my instance but app engine does it when my app doesnot get any requests.

Comment: It sounds like you're using the static initializer to precompute some data. In that case, why don't you want it to run each time a new instance is spun up? If it doesn't, you won't have access to that data.

Comment: i think you misunderstand the resident instance (like i did). the resident instance is like a persistent idle instance which serves requests until a dynamic instance is started. if you setup a resident (min idle instance) you will see that it will serve only a minimal part or even none of the requests for your app.

Answer (score 1):

Memcache data can disappear at any time. Only datastore data is guaranteed to be persistent.

You can store your initialisation data and fetch it in the order:

1. static data members(?)
2. memcache data
3. datastore data

(this is what I do) if you don't want to take up Nick's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can schedule a task that periodically runs every 10 minutes, this instance will be kept  loaded. (ensure to have threadsafe on)